Convert byte array to DateTime
I have bytes array and time value below:
Bytes: 00 05 fc 3b d1 bb c0 c2 
Time:  05/22/2023 5:38:55 am

Bytes: 00 06 07 04 94 65 f7 81
Time:  10/06/2023 11:21:51 am

I couldn’t find a solution to convert this bytes arr to datetime. I tried with this code, but its not true:
How to convert a byte[] into datetime in C#?
Please help me! Thanks you
How to convert a byte[] into datetime in C#?

What did you get when you used the code in the other answer? Do you know how the byte value was generated?

That looks like big-endian Unix time in microseconds, so: BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(data) and use that number to add an offset to 1970-01-01 (you might need to switch to milliseconds or ticks to work conveniently) - I can probably code up an example in about 4 hours when at a PC, but: not right now

I'm guessing the difference between 2023-05-22 05:38:55 and 2023-05-21 22:38:55 is timezones; presumably you're 7 hours from UTC. You'll need to compensate for that locally.
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;

byte[] bytes = [0x00, 0x05, 0xfc, 0x3b, 0xd1, 0xbb, 0xc0, 0xc2];
var unixMicros = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(bytes);

var when = UnixTime.Epoch.AddMicroseconds(unixMicros);
Console.WriteLine(when); // 21/05/2023 22:38:55

bytes = [0x00, 0x06, 0x07, 0x04, 0x94, 0x65, 0xf7, 0x81];
unixMicros = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(bytes);

when = UnixTime.Epoch.AddMicroseconds(unixMicros);
Console.WriteLine(when); // 06/10/2023 04:21:51

internal static class UnixTime
{
    public static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}

If you're on down-level .NET, you'll need to use AddTicks; hint: there are 10 ticks per microsecond.

Instead of your own UnixTime you could use DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddMicroseconds(value).

@Oliver thanks; somehow I've overlooked that one (looks like it has been there since netcoreapp2.1, so: no excuses)
